# MySQL mysqldump exporting incomplete files?

Tags: amazon-web-services, mysql

I am trying to export a MySQL database from a Amazon Web Service Relation Database Service. I have tried connecting and exporting through MySQL Workbench and tried through command line in the EC2 server. But the tables exports still end up incomplete.

One table exports the first 5459 rows (1.1Mb) and then stops half way through the row.
another table exports the first 676 rows (7.7Mb) and then stops half way through the row again, this table should have about 39000 rows.

I haven't used Amazon Wen Services before or Linux or MySQL, I normally work on Windows servers with Microsoft SQL. Has anyone had this error before or know what the cause could be?

Comment: could you add the mysqldump command you are using

Comment: From the command line, at least, there *should* be an error message if the dump process fails...

Comment: have been using the command line:
mysql -u user -p password database > backup.sql

Comment: Could this be because the RDS is a micro instance and so it doesn't have enough power to do the whole query or something???

Comment: Does MySQL have anything that limits the run time of a query?

Comment: found this was an issue with the program I was using to open the files to check them. used a different program and opened the files and the whole table was there.